# Inheritance of classes with an argument in c++

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I learn qt from Hands On Embedded Programming with Qt book.

I don't understand why I can add Inheritance m_tempSensor(id) with **id** argument when  TemperatureSensorIF constructor not expect any argument, and why as argument I give pointer to "TemperatureSensorIF."

Link to full code:

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Embedded-Programming-with-Qt/blob/master/Chapter05/BigProject/MainWindow.cpp

There is something like that:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>

class TemperatureSensorIF {
public:
    explicit TemperatureSensorIF(){

    }
};

class MainWindow: public TemperatureSensorIF{
public:
    MainWindow(TemperatureSensorIF *id);
    //~MainWindow();
private:
    TemperatureSensorIF *m_tempSensor;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(TemperatureSensorIF *id): m_tempSensor(id){
    qDebug() << "New window constructor";
}


int main()
{
    qDebug() << "Init";
    TemperatureSensorIF sensor1;
    MainWindow newWindow(&sensor1);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks ;)

Adrian

Comment: Are you really supposed to make `MainWindow` inherit from `TemperatureSensorIF`? Remember that inheritance is an *is-a* relationship. Is `MainWindow` really a `TemperatureSensorIF`? Or should it just *contain* a `TemperatureSensorIF` (which it also does, in a way)?

Comment: Also note that the code you link to does *not* inherit from `TemperatureSensorIF`.

Comment: Specifically MainWindow should contain Temperature Sensor and mocking functions to connect them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `: m_tempSensor(id)` you initialize the inherited member variable, which is different from calling the parents constructor. In your case the parent class constructor is called automatically because it has no parameters, which is equivalent to:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(TemperatureSensorIF *id): 
  TemperatureSensorIF(),
  m_tempSensor(id)
{
  qDebug() << "New window constructor";
}
```